# getent group correct but id not

Tags: linux, user-accounts, openldap, user-groups

How on earth can this be possible?

```
# getent group mailuser
mailuser:*:37103:admin,pinguin,testuser
# id testuser
uid=46944(testuser) gid=100(users) Gruppen=2399(datas),100(users)
#
```

Yes, users/groups come from openldap but the server is perfectly reachable and changes successfully reflect in `getent group` and `getent passwd`. Group mapping works for all other users on this server. I restarted the machine already.

Comment: What LDAP client are you using, and what search queries does it make on the server for these two commands?

Comment: @user1686: Debian 9 (i.e., libnss-ldap 265-5, dovecot-ldap 1:2.2.27-3+deb9u5). I will check if I can find the queries on the server. However, my main question is: How can these two be different in the first place? And, `id` returns the correct result after a long time. But I restarted the VM (+nscd) and the LDAP server. Super weird.